# Proper way of creating users and restricting permissions?

Tags: bash, permissions, users, groups

I want to create a user, allocate a home directory to the user and restrict their rwx permissions such that they can only stay/view the home directory. I want to hide `/etc/apache2` and `/var/www` mainly.

I've tried:

```
useradd newuser
groupadd newgroup
usermod -g newgroup newuser
chmod g+rwx /home/newuser
chgrp -R /home/newuser
```

And it all seems well, but when I `su newuser`, I get `bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied`, and it'd probably mean other applications probably will suffer also. So what is the proper way to achieve what I need?

Note: this is for a server, so no GUI and the newuser will require ssh access (at least).

Comment: Not really, I could `setfacl -R -m u:newuser:--- /var/www` for every directory that I want hidden. It's just not clean and not exactly future proof.

Comment: `chgrp -R /home/newuser` is missing the group argument. Depending on what the user should be able to do, they will need access to files outside of their home directory. But I don't understand how the commands you listed above would prevent the user from accessing `/bin/bash` or `/etc/bash.bashrc`, since both files (and their folders) should have appropriate read/execute permissions for `others`. Have you changed any file permissions except for `/home/newuser`?

Comment: My point was, anyone with admin privileges can reverse `setfacl` or whatever you use to restrict access.